# File Upload Size Limit SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have been searching around to find out what would be the max file size you can upload and recommended into SharePoint.
If i need to cap it at 30MB is there any other thing i need to setup in IIS etc.. to make sure SharePoint can handle it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

File Upload size limit in SP2013 is 250 MB and in SP2010 is 50 MB.
You can configure it from Central Admin :

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sammykailini/archive/2013/11/06/how-to-increase-the-maximum-upload-size-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx